# Is a majorable subset in lp is relatively compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

Let A be a nonempty set in the sequence space lp with 1 ≤ p < +∞.
I want to show that if A is majorable then it is relatively compact.
A is majorable by definition if there exists y ∈ lp such that
|x(k)| ≤ |y(k)|, for all x ∈ A, k ∈ N.
I know that A is relatively compact if and only if it is totally bounded and if and only if every sequence in A has a subsequence that converges in lp.
I thought that i could use this theorem to prove my thesis but i couldn't come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}_n$ be any sequence in $A$.  For every  $k$ one has that the sequence of scalars
$$
  \{x_n(k)\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}
  $$
is  bounded by $|y(k)|$, so it admits a converging sub-sequence.  By doing this for each $k$, and using Cantor's diagonal
argument, we may find  a sequence $n_1<n_2<\cdots \quad$ of natural numbers, such that
$$
  z(k) := \lim_{i\to \infty } x_{n_i}(k)
  $$
exists for every $k$.  Since $|z(k)|\leq |y(k)|$, it is obvious that $z := (z(k))_k$ lies in $\ell^p$.  Moreover
$$
  \lim_{i\to \infty }\|x_{n_i} - z\|^p =
  \lim_{i\to \infty }\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_{n_i}(k) - z(k)|^p = 0,
  $$
by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem.  This proves that every sequence in $A$ has a converging sub-sequence (to a
point in $\ell^p$), so $A$ is relatively compact.